# SVN: How to automagically remove the Working Copy but preserve ignored items?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, working-copy

I currently have a Working Copy with two branches in it:

```
/Source
/Source/v1.2
/Source/v1.3
```

I want to delete this and instead only check out the branch I need (i.e. go one level down the directory tree and only check out /Source/v1.3).  However the working copy of v1.3 contains a bunch of ignored files that I actually want to keep.  So I don't want to just delete the whole working copy and start over.  And of course I don't want to manually try to locate all of the ignored files and preserve them.  Is there any sort of command to do this?

I'm on Windows using TortoiseSVN as well as Slik SVN for automated builds.

Comment: Alright, so I hope this isn't too bad of form to answer my own (first) question but I hope it might help others.  Here's what I did:

1. Copy the v1.3 folder out of the Source folder. 2. Delete the Source folder. 3. Create a new Source folder. 4. Move the v1.3 copy under Source.

So the Source folder is no longer part of the working copy and none of the paths have been changed.  Makes perfect sense in retrospect (and I love the fact you can move working copies where-ever you want!).

Comment: @Josh - it is not bad form to answer your own question. Just make it an answer and accept it instead of making it a comment.

Comment: @Josh - You can add your solution as an answer and accept it. Also, you can export the properties for a file/folder (all of the `svn:ignore` properties). You can then import them for another file/folder.

Comment: Hi all.  Thanks for the replies!  I actually tried that, but it won't let me answer my own question within 8 hours.  I'll add it as an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Josh That worked in this case. The solution for cases in which you can't (or don't want to) move around folders would be to use `svn switch --force`, assuming I remember correctly.

Comment: @DevNull: I think @Josh was interested in keeping the *actual* ignored files, not the ignore list.

Comment: @s.m.: yes that is exactly correct.

Comment: In retrospect I think I could have done this as well: 1. Delete the v1.2 folder. 2. Delete the .svn folder under Source.  Probably the same effect?

Comment: Ahh. I misunderstood. +1 for a good question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sub-directory tree in Subversion is its own working directory. It contains everything you need in order to use it as a working directory. This includes the directories and files that are being ignored, revision history, etc.

There is no reason why you can't simply use the sub-directory you want as your new working directory and delete the rest. In fact, you can even rename the top sub-directory tree once you get it out of the way. In this example, you're moving the v1.3 directory to the C:\ drive and renaming it \Source-v1.3. Then, deleting the rest:

```
C:\> cd \Source
C:\Source> move v1.3 \Source-v1.3
C:\Source> cd ..
C:\> rd Source /s/q
C:\> cd Source-v1.3
C:\Source-v1.3> svn update
```

This will keep all of the files and directories you've ignored, ignored.

Comment: Thanks! In fact it's even simpler; delete the v1.2 folder and delete the .svn folder under Source.  In this way the path to the v1.3 folder doesn't change (which is part of what I wanted; I have non-relative paths I wanted to avoid editing).  Sorry I don't have enough rep to +1 your answer, but I do appreciate it.

Comment: FWIW, it would appear the changes to working copies in Subversion 1.7 break this ability :(  Working copies no longer contain a .svn folder in each subfolder; the .svn folder is now only present at the root of the working copy.  Bummer :(